# How to plot errorbars on seaborn barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, errorbar

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'Value':[6.25, 4.55, 4.74, 1.36, 2.56, 1.4, 3.55, 3.21, 3.2, 3.65, 3.45, 3.86, 13.9, 10.3, 15], 
        'Name':['Peter', 'Anna', 'Luke',
                 'Peter', 'Anna', 'Luke',
                 'Peter', 'Anna', 'Luke',
                 'Peter', 'Anna', 'Luke',
                 'Peter', 'Anna', 'Luke'],
        'Param': ['Param1', 'Param1', 'Param1', 
                 'Param2', 'Param2', 'Param2', 
                 'Param3', 'Param3', 'Param3', 
                 'Param4', 'Param4', 'Param4',
                 'Param5', 'Param5', 'Param5'],
        'error': [2.55, 1.24, 0, 0.04, 0.97, 0, 0.87, 0.7, 0, 0.73, 0.62, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I'd like to add errorbars (pre-defined in the error column) to the bar plot, but I can't seem to get the x-coordinates right? It shows errorbars for `Param5` but there are no errors for `Param5`? Also for `Luke`, there are no errors, but in `Param1` an errorbar is plotted.

```
plt.figure()
ax = sns.barplot(x = 'Param', y = 'Value', data = df, hue = 'Name', palette = sns.color_palette('CMRmap_r', n_colors = 3))
x_coords = [p.get_x() + 0.5*p.get_width() for p in ax.patches]
y_coords = [p.get_height() for p in ax.patches]
plt.errorbar(x=x_coords, y=y_coords, yerr=df["error"], fmt="none", c= "k")
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bars in `ax.patches` come ordered by `hue` value.  To get the bars and the dataframe in the same order, the dataframe could be sorted first by `Name` and then by `Param`:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = {'Value': [6.25, 4.55, 4.74, 1.36, 2.56, 1.4, 3.55, 3.21, 3.2, 3.65, 3.45, 3.86, 13.9, 10.3, 15],
        'Name': ['Peter', 'Anna', 'Luke',
                 'Peter', 'Anna', 'Luke',
                 'Peter', 'Anna', 'Luke',
                 'Peter', 'Anna', 'Luke',
                 'Peter', 'Anna', 'Luke'],
        'Param': ['Param1', 'Param1', 'Param1',
                  'Param2', 'Param2', 'Param2',
                  'Param3', 'Param3', 'Param3',
                  'Param4', 'Param4', 'Param4',
                  'Param5', 'Param5', 'Param5'],
        'error': [2.55, 1.24, 0, 0.04, 0.97, 0, 0.87, 0.7, 0, 0.73, 0.62, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.sort_values(['Name', 'Param'])

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
ax = sns.barplot(x='Param', y='Value', data=df, hue='Name', palette='CMRmap_r')
x_coords = [p.get_x() + 0.5 * p.get_width() for p in ax.patches]
y_coords = [p.get_height() for p in ax.patches]
ax.errorbar(x=x_coords, y=y_coords, yerr=df["error"], fmt="none", c="k")
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot with custom error bars]

PS: Note that by default, the columns are sorted alphabetically.  If you want to maintain the original order, you can make the column categorical via `pd.Categorical(df['Name'], df['Name'].unique())`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Name'] = pd.Categorical(df['Name'], df['Name'].unique())
df['Param'] = pd.Categorical(df['Param'], df['Param'].unique())
df = df.sort_values(['Name', 'Param'])
```

[image: sns.barplot with erorbars in original order]

Comment: In case you have your barplot in the other orientation, the `x_coord` should be `[p.get_width() for p in ax.patches]` and the `y_coord` should be `[p.get_y() + 0.5* p.get_height() for p in ax.patches]`. And instead of `yerr`, the argument should be `xerr`