# Adding custom errorbars to seaborn FacetGrid acknowledging hue and categorical x order

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have a dataset with precomputed means and standard deviations. The values depend on three different categorical values. I would like to create two barplots to split the first categorical variable across them. The other two categorical values should be separated on the x-axis and by using different colors.

In `seaborn` terms, I want to create barplots with `seaborn.catplot` based on categorical `x` and accustoming `order` as well as `hue` and `col` arguments while being able to add my own custom standard deviations.

The following code gives the means of the barplots pretty straightforward:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

tip_sumstats = (tips.groupby(["day", "sex", "smoker"])
                     .total_bill
                     .agg(["mean", 'sem'])
                     .reset_index())

sns.catplot(
    data=tip_sumstats,
    x="day",
    order=["Sun", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat"],
    y="mean",
    hue="smoker",
    col="sex",
    kind="bar",
    height=4,
)
```

[image]

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30428808/10106730) solves the problem when `hue` and `order` are not involved. However, in the above case, using

```py
def errplot(x, y, yerr, **kwargs):
    ax = plt.gca()
    data = kwargs.pop("data")
    data.plot(x=x, y=y, yerr=yerr, kind="bar", ax=ax, **kwargs)

g = sns.FacetGrid(tip_sumstats, col="sex", hue="smoker", height=4)
g.map_dataframe(errplot, "day", "mean", "sem")
```

results in
[image]

I do not understand how to modify this version such that it respects the categorical order on the x-axis defined by some `order` argument. Furthermore, I do not understand how to add a `dodge=True` to it such that the differently colored bars appear next to each other.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72352491/how-to-plot-errorbars-on-seaborn-barplot) tries to solve something similar.
However, the approach is very technical and not straightforward at all. To me, it seems weird that no straightforward solution exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seaborn doesn't support this out-of-the-box, probably because the many options for error bars are complicated to fit with the ways parameters are passed around.

For your specific situation, you could calculate the positions as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
tip_sumstats = (tips.groupby(["day", "sex", "smoker"])
                .total_bill
                .agg(["mean", 'sem'])
                .reset_index())


def errplot(x, y, data, order, hue, yerr, palette='deep', color=None):
    xs = np.arange(len(order))
    hues = data[hue].unique()
    dodge_width = 0.8
    dodge_vals = np.linspace(-dodge_width / 2, dodge_width / 2, len(hues)*2+1)[1::2]
    colors = sns.color_palette(palette, len(hues))
    for hue_val, dodge_val, color in zip(hues, dodge_vals, colors):
        ys = [data[(data[x] == xi) & (data[hue] == hue_val)][y].to_numpy()[0] for xi in order]
        yerrs = [data[(data[x] == xi) & (data[hue] == hue_val)][yerr].to_numpy()[0] for xi in order]
        plt.bar(x=xs + dodge_val, height=ys, yerr=yerrs, width=dodge_width / len(hues), color=color, label=hue_val)
    plt.xticks(xs, order)


g = sns.FacetGrid(tip_sumstats, col="sex", height=4)
g.map_dataframe(errplot, "day", "mean", hue="smoker", yerr="sem", order=["Sun", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat"])
g.fig.legend(*g.axes.flat[-1].get_legend_handles_labels(), title='smoker')
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.catplot with custom error bars]

Comment: Is `dodge_width=0.8` the default parameter seaborn uses? Is there an informative website to find out which default parameters seaborn uses in such cases?

Comment: The [sns.barplot docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) give a default `width=0.8`. ( [sns.catplot docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) refers to `barplot` for the specific keywords).  Other than that, the source can be found at github.